How do I change background colour (overall)?
I have a huge CSS file, with lots of . selectors in it.
But there is no selector in the file, which is responsible for the overall background colour.
How can I change the background colour in this case?
Thank you

if there is no selector to define backgroud color in the file so first we need to define the selector:
you can add backgroud color tag in body . either use a universal selector using (*) in css and define background color.
i hope it will be helpful for you

Hi, thanks! You mean, in body, in php file (html) right? - First place in body, then corresponding code in css file. - Will check this out - Thanks
